# Translating relational model to SQL code(Quick)

Tags: sql

**Question:**

The relational model says dramatist_no OR A_no can be a primary key for this table. I believe my SQL code is correct but instead defines the attributes PK(dramatist_no, A_no) to be both PK. Would my SQL code be correct or do I have to change something regarding dramatist_no, A_no ?

**Relational Model:**

ACTOR_DRAM(dramatist_no, A_no)

PK(dramatist_no) or PK(A_no)

FK(dramatist_no) references DRAMATIST(dramatist_no)

FK(A_no) references Actor_Born_Lives(A_NO)

**SQL Code:**

```
create table ACTOR_DRAM ( \

   dramatist_no integer NOT NULL, \
   A_no integer NOT NULL, \
   constraint fk_dramatist_no \
   foreign key(dramatist_no) \
   references DRAMATIST(dramatist_no) \
   on delete restrict, \
   constraint fk_A_no \
   foreign key(A_no) \
   references Actor_Born_Lives(A_NO) \
   on delete restrict, \
   primary key(dramatist_no, A_no) )
```

Comment: Yes, there is a `not null` constraint that you can specify on columns, or you could make dramatist_no + A_no a composite primary key. Without knowing anything about your model it's impossible to say what would be correct.

Comment: So would making both attributes NOT NULL in the SQL table solve this problem? Because logically thinking, I'm not really fixing it Im just putting a constraint saying it HAS to have both these attributes. But in reality an actor is not always a dramatist. So I'm guessing a composite primary key is better?

Comment: I don't know what problem you're trying to solve so I can't say, but anyway you have accepted an answer so I guess the question is resolved.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question(it is still the same, but more detailed) for you to understand more because I guess my question was ambiguous please take a look when you can..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do more research into the purpose of a primary key. I primary key uniquely identifies the records in a table. In your table there appears to be a many to many relationship between actors and dramatists.

If I understand your question, what you want is a lookup table. You want to implement this as a three column table. A actorid foreign key, a dramatistid foreign key and a auto incremented primary key relation id.

Comment: I edited my question just take a look so you can understand it more I added more details so you can understand what I'm talking about.